# how to streamline ubuntu installation ? (started from ubuntu mini)

Tags: system-installation

does any body know how to streamline ubuntu installation ?

i mean, i start installing my computer using ubuntu 10.10 mini (12,7MB) and after finish it takes about 800MB of my space (system with terminal only).
then add LXDE + abiword + gnumeric and it's size getting bigger more than 1 GB.

i try to make iso using relinux and it's size about 810 MB (have to burn to DVD) :'(

just curious, how ubuntu developer create such full functional system and shipped it with CD around the world ?

Answer (score 0):

The technology on the live CD is squashfs. If you extract the root.squashfs from the Ubuntu live CD, and decompress it , its is a few GB.

See

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

and [man squashfs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/mksquashfs.1.html)

If Ubuntu is too large for you, try Debian. Part of the reason Ubuntu is user friendly is that some packages have more then the bare minimal dependencies. Debian will have less dependencies, so you may be able to get a (slightly) smaller OS.

If that is still too large, then you have to look at alternate OS, anything from tinycore to gentoo to slax.